# When hovering over main menu all submenus show

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, show-hide, submenu

I know this question is already answered in other ways before, but I don't know how to implement it. I've been trying to modify a demo_menu that is responsive and suitable for mobile devices. The [demo](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/drop-down-responsive-menu-with-css3-jquery.html) did not have a submenu inside a submenu so I tried to make one, but now I have this hover problem.

Here's [my](http://jsfiddle.net/Ter747474/QW8j8/2/) example.

```
<div class="container">
<header>
    <!-- start header here-->
    <header>
        <div id="fdw">
            <!--nav-->
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Who we are<span class="arrow"></span></a>

                        <ul style="display: none;"
                        class="sub_menu">
                            <li class="arrow_top"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Jane</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Joe</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our servicese<span class="arrow"></span></a>

                        <ul style="display: none;"
                        class="sub_menu">
                            <li class="arrow_top"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Classes</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Camping</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Coaching</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Stables</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Prices</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery<span class="arrow"></span></a>

                        <ul style="display: none;"
                        class="sub_menu">
                            <li class="arrow_top"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Horses<span class="arrow"></span></a>

                                <ul style="display:none;"
                                class="sub_menu2">
                                    <li><a href="#">Horse A</a>

                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Horse B</a>

                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Horse C</a>

                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">etc</a>

                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Location</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Competition</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Theme days</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>    <a href="#">Contact<span class="arrow"></span></a>

                        <ul style="display: none;"
                        class="sub_menu">
                            <li class="arrow_top"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Feedback</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Guestbook</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- end fdw -->
    </header>
    <!-- end header -->
```

```
// show and hide sub menu
$(function () {
$('nav ul li').hover(

function () {
    //show its submenu
    $('ul', this).slideDown(150);
},

function () {
    //hide its submenu
    $('ul', this).slideUp(150);
});
});
//end
```

My skills are limited only in basic html and css, so I might be over my head here.

Any help is a appreciated.

Comment: your jsfiddle link is broken. please edit.

Comment: Try to place your code here. If fiddle is broken so your code will be a future reference to the next visitor.

Comment: Just a slight bit of confusion. You said this was for a mobile menu. How do you hover on a mobile device? I'm not sure hover is the appropriate route for a mobile device.

Comment: No need to down vote guys. He is a newbie and simply trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is this: http://jsfiddle.net/QW8j8/4/

```
$('nav ul li').hover(

function () {
    //show its submenu
    $('> ul', this).slideDown(150);
}, //--^---------------------------apply to the direct children not grandchildren

function () {
    //hide its submenu
    $('> ul', this).slideUp(150);
});//--^---------------------------apply to the direct children not grandchildren
```

Comment: The simplest fix by Jai.
@Ter747474 What you are doing is calling for all the ul inside the menu item that you are hovering. "> ul" instead of simple "ul" ensures that you are selecting only the direct descendant. That means if you hover over a list item say "li" it will only "slideDown" "li > ul" and not "li > ul > li > ul".

Comment: Thank you Jai, thank you so much. I've tried to solve this for three days! Thanks you Jehanzeb.Malik for the encouragement.

Comment: and yes don't forget to accept it if this satisfies your issues.

Comment: War10ck. The part of the script that is displayed here is for normal browsing. But if you look at the code in jsFiddle and resize your browser window you can see the effect.